# How to import dependencies using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I apologize for my noob question, however i cannot understand how i import dependencies using gradle.

I have tried importing `sqlite4java`and my `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile "com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:1.0.392"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have tried using:

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteStatement;
```

To import the `sqlite4java` classes but i keep getting compiler errors when i run `gradle build`.

How do i access the `sqlite4java` classes.

Comment: Check this topic in the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle/3289/declare-dependencies/11289/how-to-add-a-repository#t=201609150734182370102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that problem is you didn't attach central maven repository to your project. Try to modify your `repositories` section:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.